# Toggle disabled attribute to a specific element id in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a dashboard that creates cards based on an array , which you can edit and delete. However i cant figure out how to disable or enable the fields that belong to a specific card. I tried using id but the attribute disabled is read-only .How can i do i accomplish the behavior i described?

Below is the code i have tried to use

HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let caso of tarea">
 <div class="card shadow-box">
                            <div class="card-header bg-danger"> 
                                <div class="row">
                                    <h4 style="color: black;"  class="card-title col-8">Caso : {{caso.nombre}}</h4>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info mr-2 mb-3" (click)="toogleEdit(caso._id)"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mr-2 mb-3" (click)="removerCaso(caso._id)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body bg-yellow">
                                <h3 style="color: black;" class="text-capitalize"> Cliente : {{caso.cliente}}</h3>
                                    
                                        <label style="color: black;"  for="tema-{{caso._id}}">Tema : </label>
                                        <input  style="color: black;" [attr.disabled]="true" type="text" id="tema-{{caso._id}}" value="{{caso.tema}}">
                                        <br>
                                        <label style="color: black;" for="desc-{{caso._id}}">Descripcion : </label>
                                         <textarea style="color: black;" [attr.disabled]="true" class="col-12" type="text" id="desc-{{caso._id}}"  >{{caso.descripcion}}</textarea>
                                    
                                   
                                
                                <span class="col-8"><button routerLink="/manager/{{caso._id}}" class="btn btn-primary" style="color: black;"  >Administrar Actividades</button></span>
                                <span class="col-4" *ngIf="caso.estado===2">
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteCaso(caso)">Borrar del dashboard</button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                    </div>
</ng-container>
```

TS:

```
toogleEdit(id){
      if(document.getElementById("tema-"+id).attributes["disabled"]==true){
         console.log("true")
         document.getElementById("tema-"+id).attributes["disabled"]=false
      }else {
         console.log("false")
         document.getElementById("tema-"+id).attributes["disabled"]=true
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `removeAttribute`, `setAttribute` and `getAttribute`.

A problem you have is both the `input` and `textarea` have the same id and this is a no-no. An id has to be unique to the HTML page.

```
toogleEdit(id){
      if (!!document.getElementById("tema-"+id).getAttribute('disabled')){
         console.log("true")
         document.querySelector(`input#tema-${id}`).removeAttribute('disabled');
         document.querySelector(`textarea#tema-${id}`)
                 .removeAttribute('disabled');
      } else {
         console.log("false")
         document.querySelector(`input#tema-${id}`).setAttribute('disabled', '');
         document.querySelector(`textarea#tema-${id`)
                 .setAttribute('disabled', '');
      }
   }
```

However, try doing it the Angular way where you can bookkeep which input is disabled or enabled.

Something like this:

```
enabledDisabledState = tarea.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr._id] = false;
  return acc;
}, {}); // make an object of { 'casoId1': false, 'casoId2': false ... }


....
toogleEdit(id){
     // every time toogleEdit is called, set it to the opposite
      this.enabledDisabledState[id] = !this.enabledDisabledState[id];
   }

...
// HTML
[attr.disabled] = "enabledDisabledState[caso._id]"
```

Comment: I want to toggle both input and textarea at the same time if possible though , in your implementation would i have to use two different sets of ids?

Comment: I would use different id's. I have edited my answer to use `querySelector` and be specific about input and textarea.

Comment: I can set the disabled attribute using this answer however i cant remove the attribute after setting it even though it detects correctly that the attribute is set

Comment: Try doing it the Angular way. Ideally you shouldn't be using `document`.

Comment: same thing happened using angular way